# I can no longer move the Tor Browser window around the screen (Mac)

Tags: mac

I always used to be able to move the Tor Browser Window around the screen to place it wherever I wanted, just like any other open window. I have suddenly found that no matter what I do, it will not move anywhere, it's just stuck in the middle of the screen. I can resize the window from the corners as normal, but I often need to move the browser to the edge of the screen. Any ideas why this happened and how I can make the window move-able again?
Cheers

Running Mac OS Sierra 10.12
Tried the usual turning everything off and on again etc
Searched through settings/preferences but cant seem to find any option that could have made the browser window just stuck there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The drag region is upside down.
You can drag the window around from the bottom of the browser.
Not a joke, by the way. Try it for yourself.
Until the bug is fixed, this will have to do.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it's a known bug in Tor Browser, a fix is being worked by the Tor Browser developers at the moment. It's being tracked on the Tor Project bug tracker on ticket [#20204](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/20204).

It may be worthwhile keeping an eye on the [Tor Project Blog](https://blog.torproject.org/) for new release announcements (it should reference the aforementioned bug number). I'll also try to update this (or maybe some other good citizen can edit it for me) once the fix has been applied and pushed out to users.